# How to dynamically add a property to an instance in groovy

Tags: grails, properties, groovy

I have piece of code as follows

```
def revisedSections=sections.collect{sectionObj->
  sectionObj.questionCategories=sectionObj.questionCategories.collect{qCat->
    def flag=false
    this.questionSet.questions = this.questionSet.questions.collect{qObj->
      if(qCat.category == qObj.questionCategory.category){
        qCat.questions.add(qObj)
        //this.questionSet.questions.remove(qObj)
        flag=true
      }
      qObj
    }
    if(flag){
      qCat
    }
  }
  sectionObj
}
log.debug('revisedSections'+revisedSections)
this.metaClass.getSectionsData={-> revisedSections }
log.debug 'this.sectionsData '+this.sectionsData
```

I want to add sectionsData property to the instance and then convert the instance to json
but i am not able to access the dynamically added property with this code, is there something i am missing ?

Comment: Do you have an example that can be executed to exhibit the problem you say you have?

Comment: i am sorry, it's not possible for me to share the complete code, but i'll try to explain what scenario is....I have a class which i cannot modify and want to add a property to the instances of it so that when i convert the instance to json it will have that custom property for use on client side....here i have a collection called "revisedSections" which i want to add to the instance as the custom property...is it not possilbe to assign the collections like this ?

Comment: I wasn't after the complete code, just an executable example showing what you are trying to do, as I don't understand the question...

Comment: oh..actually instead of logging i tried printing the newly added property and it actually printed the added value...so i believe the problem is with the json conversion...is there any way to make json converter(i am using grails' default json converter) convert this custom property ?

Comment: @tim_yates thanks for looking into this....sorry for not being clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixins to accomplish what you're looking for. Something like the following is native and acceptable Groovy:

```
class RevisedSection {
    String sectionData
}

class Section {
    String name
}

Section.mixin RevisedSection

def section = new Section(sectionData: "Data", name: "Section Name")

assert section.sectionData == "Data"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for replying...the metaprogramming approach does work..but for my usecase i need to convert the instance to json..and want the dynamically added property to convert to json(which grails' default json converter skips) do you know any way of making it convert the dynamic property aswell?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve correctly, it is easily feasible with meta programming, and it should work.

Without information about the context of your code I can only guess at the base class of your object etc, so here's some code run in the groovy console, which works perfectly

```
class D {
 int someValue

 def init() {
  this.metaClass.getSomeString={->someValue as String}
 }
}
def d=new D()
d.init()
d.someValue=76
println d.someString
```

The result is of course the string '76' being printed to the console.

Another suggestion, with a  statically compiled getter:

```
class D {
  private Closure computation
  int someValue

 def init() {
  this.computation={someValue}
 }
 String  getSomeString(){
     computation() as String
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying...actually i figured out the problem. the problem is with json conversion...grails' default json converter doesn't convert dynamically added property to json, do you know any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Maybe by changing the object representation of your model to be converted to a Map, and then adding the property as a key in the Map. Something else that may be worth trying is adding the method to the Class metaclass, not to the instance? Maybe this is picked up by JSON. The third thing which should work is craete a method getXXX(){xxxClosure()} which delegates to a closure xxxClosure which is then assigned by yout init block.

Comment: Yeah, this method certainly won't work because the metaClass property never gets serialized. Additionally, the provided example is missing both proper typing and setter methods.

Comment: will mixins get serialized ? also i want to add the dynamic property on a per instance basis and not for the whole class

Comment: mixins will not work on a per-instance basis, mixins add code at compile time. I am pretty certain that my 3rd suggestion should work.

Comment: @loteq can you please elaborate the third suggestion a bit more? i have not used anything like that before.

Comment: I will have to edit my response to post the code, follow me there